# Post request from AngularJS to Restful web service

Tags: angularjs

I make login page in AngularJS, After submit form, data will be post to Restfull web service to check existence of account, if success return "success" and return "Failed" if failed

Web service:

```
@POST
@Path(value = "login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String login(@FormParam("email")String email, @FormParam("pass") String pass){
    UserModel um = new UserModel();
    Nguoichoi nc = um.find(email.trim(), pass.trim());
    if (nc != null){
        return "Success";
    } else { 
        return "Failed";
    }
}
```

AngularJS function:

```
app.controller("LoginController", function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.login = function(){
            var encodeString = "email=" + this.email + "&pass=" + this.pass;
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/HocvuiWebservices/rest/user/login",
                data: encodeString,
                headers: {'Accept':' text/plain', 'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data);
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(headers);
                console.log(config);
                console.log("Error submit form");
            });
        }
    });
```

Form login:

```
<form class="login-form" ng-submit="login()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email: </label> <input
                        type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email"
                        placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password: </label> <input
                        type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="pass"
                        placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label> <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Loginp</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a ui-sref="dangky" class="text-primary">Register</a>
            </form>
```

But when i submit form, the post request return error "Error submit form", although post request connect success to Restful web service?

Comment: Could you post the error logs

Comment: Shouldn't `this.email` and `this.pass` be `$scope.email` and `$scope.pass`?

Comment: what HTTP status code is returned from API call?

Comment: @Konkko: this is my console.log in error branch      console.log(data);
console.log(status);
console.log(headers);
console.log(config);
console.log("Error submit form");  => null UIroute.html:96:6
-1
function bd/<()
Object { method: "POST", transformRequest: Array[1], transformResponse: Array[1], paramSerializer: jf/this.$get/<(), url: "http://localhost:8080/HocvuiWebserv…", data: "email=abc0511@gmail.com&pass=123456", headers: Object } UIroute.html:99:6
Error submit form

Comment: @Lex: i changed $scope.email....but same error

Comment: @danday74: console.log(status) = -1